# Forest Fire network sampling in R

Tags: r, graph, igraph, sampling

I'm looking for an algorithm implementation of Fire Forest sampling (FFS) in R.

found this:
http://cneurocvs.rmki.kfki.hu/igraph/doc/R/forest.fire.game.html

but, this implementation doesn't sample from a graph (it only generate a graph)

I would like to sample from a real graph using FFS.

Thanks for all helpers

Comment: `sample_forestfire` in `igraph`  is what you are looking for I think...

Comment: Thanks but it looks like this function is identical to the forest.fire.game {igraph} function. It does not sample from a graph, but rather generates a new network.